Is it possible to redefine or create a new dunder method to built in objects like int?
I’m trying to define a new type of division such that 1/0 doesn’t raise a ZeroDivisionError, instead, it returns a new object called infty(0), which is defined as follow:
class infty:
   
   def __init__(self, sign:int):
      if sign > 0:
         self.sign = 1
      elif sign < 0:
         self.sign = -1
      else:
         self.sign = 0
   
   def __repr__(self):
      if self.sign > 0:
         return '∞'
      if self.sign < 0:
         return '-∞'
      return '?'

so I have made a new function:
def safediv(a:int, b:int) -> float|infty:
   if b == 0:
      return infty(0)
   return a/b

and tried to assign it to truediv by int.__truediv__ = safediv
but it fails with the error message:
    int.__truediv__ = safediv
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot set '__truediv__' attribute of immutable type 'int'

Is there a way to achieve the effect that 1/0 returns infty(0)?

No. Because int is immutable. That means "can't be changed". And 1 and 0 are both int. Alternatively, write your own language. Then you can make int whatever you want. Best of luck!

@Elliott Instances of int are immutable. That doesn't mean the class per se is immutable. (I'm not necessarily saying what OP wants is possible, just that "int immutability" does not mean what you mean.)

@deceze That was my first reaction too, but the class is also immutable, at least in CPython, as it shows in OP's error: immutable type 'int'

In fairness, immutable types have only been a thing since CPython 3.10, it seems :)

So there is no absolutely way to achieve such an effect? I saw some said about forbiddenfruit although I don’t fully understand its meaning

@Mr.W yes you can achieve such an effect with hacks to the language, which forbiddenfruit does. It would never, ever be a good idea to actually do this in a real environment, but for toying around with the language you can. forbiddenfruit is a C extension which can patch built in classes even if they’re implemented in C (and thus immutable from the point of view of Python).
